# Complex and multiple connected database relations in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database-design, entity-relationship, aggregation, table-relationships

I am currently trying to model a MongoDB database structure where the entities are very complex in relation to each other.

In my current collections, MongoDB queries are difficult or impossible to put into a single aggregation. Incidentally, I'm not a database specialist and have been working with MongoDB for only about half a year.

To keep it as simple as possible but necessary, this is my challenge:

I have newspaper **articles** that contain **simple keywords**, **works** (oevres, books, movies), **persons** and **linked combinations of works and persons**. In addition, the same people appear under different names in different articles.

Later, on the person view I want to show the following:

- the links of the person with name and work and the respective articles

  the articles in which the person appears without a work (by name)

  the other keywords that are still in the article

In my structure I want to avoid that entities such as people occur multiple times. So these are my current collections:

```
Article
id
title
keywordRelations
```

```
KeywordRelation
id
type (single or combination)
simpleKeywordId (optional)
personNameConnectionIds (optional)
workIds (optional)
```

```
SimpleKeyword
id
value
```

```
PersonNameConnection
id
personId
nameInArticleId
```

```
Person
id
firstname
lastname
```

```
NameInArticle
id
name
type (e.g. abbreviation, synonyme)
```

```
Work
id
title
```

To meet the requirements, I would always have to create queries that range over 3 to 4 tables. Is that possible and useful with MongoDB?

Or is there an easier way and structure to achieve that?

Comment: This is basically SQL design, which won't work well with MongoDB. Generally schema design in MongoDB aims for how data can be retrieved faster with no joins in a single `find()`, as opposed to SQL design which prioritizes normalization (like what you did here). I suggest you take a look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models/ and determine if MongoDB is a good fit for your use case.

Comment: Thank you. You're right. I have to rethink the whole structure of my database. I can store certain information and relations well in the article collection itself. It's hard for me to decide when MongoDB will need an extra collection for edges or ralations and when to store the relation information in an embedded collection itself.

Comment: If MongoDB is new to you, I would suggest you to take some free MongoDB university courses in https://university.mongodb.com to get familiar with the idea behind the philosophy. Database design is typically a crucial step, and getting it wrong could be expensive to change in the future. Once you get the hang of the technology, try to stress test the design. We can provide further help once we know if there's anything that can be improved based on your testing and your desired result.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about these courses. Thank you very much!